# Загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: jquery, upload

Интересен принцип реализации **drag-and-drop** для загрузки файлов на сервер. Если написать

```
<input type='file' />
```

Файл можно перетащить мышкой, но при этом на экране будут стандартные элементы - **выберите файл**, **файл не выбран**. Значит принцип должен быть другим. Каким?

Работаю с jQuery и  библиотекой ajaxUpload. Есть готовые фреймворки для работы с файлами, но хотелось бы реализовать все самому. При этом я не прошу готового кода, а только принцип реализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Выбор файлов с помощью перетаскивания](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Будем разбираться